# Evaluating a sum $\sum_{r=0}^{10} r \binom{10}{r} 3^r (-2)^{10-r}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We have to evaluate this:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{10} r \binom{10}{r} 3^r (-2)^{10-r}$$

What i started doing is expand the binomial coefficient as:

$$r\binom{10}{r} = \dfrac{10!}{(10-r)!\ (r-1)!} = 10 \binom{9}{r-1}$$

Also we take $3$ common to get the sum:

$$10\cdot3\sum_{r=1}^{10} \binom{9}{r-1} 3^{r-1} (-2)^{9-(r-1)}$$

which is same as

$$30(3-2)^9 = 30$$

But answer is given as $\boxed{15}$?

Comment: MuPAD says your answer is correct, and I confirm, all your computations are OK :-)

Comment: Another approach: evaluate $$\sum_0^{10}{10\choose r}3^r(-2)^{10-r}x^r$$ then differentiate, then set $x=1$.

Comment: I believe the sum is 30.

Comment: Nicolas and sharding4: Thanks! I think there might be printing error.

Comment: Gerry: Nice alternate approach, much simpler!